# How to save the file name with current date and time in PySpark?

Tags: azure, file, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse

I have a data frame in PySpark and would like to save the file as a CSV with the current timestamp as a file name. I am executing this in Azure Synapse Notebook and would like to run the notebook every day.

I stored my data frame as "df"

Using the below code, saving file as {date}.csv

```py
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%I:%M:%S_%p")

df.coalesce(1).write.option("mode","append").option("header","true").option("sep",",").csv("abfss://livetwt@strcxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/{date}.csv")
```

I am saving the CSV file in the data lake and it saving as "{date}.csv" as a folder and inside I can see the CSV file.

[image]

Inside folder

[image]

**Required Output:**

I need the file name to be "29-06-2022 15:30:25 PM.csv" without creating a new folder. I am running the notebook every day so each day, the file will be in the current date format.

Can anyone advise, what is the issue in the above code?

Note that I need to execute this only in PySpark, not in Python.

Comment: you're implementation looks correct , however I would change - `df.coalesce(1).write.option("mode","append").option("header","true").option("sep",",").csv(f"abfss://livetwt@strcxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/{date}.csv")`


using `f` to resolve the `date` variable you created , shd do the trick

Comment: pyspark will always create a folder with the provided name and use its internal nomenclature for the file name inside the folder.

Comment: You can either do renaming/moving of the file as desired after you write it, or you convert to pandas dataframe and write it out as desired (if the dataset is small enough). Pyspark will not allow you to name your file to your choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `+` to separate file path string values with variables as below

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%I:%M:%S_%p")

df.to_csv("abfss://<container_name>@<storage_accountname>.dfs.core.windows.net/from/file1_"+date+".csv", sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

[image]

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You do everything right, just add an `f` before the string. Then it will accept the `date` variable:

```py
.csv(f"abfss://livetwt@strcxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/{date}.csv")
```

Comment: It's still worth mentioning that this command will **create a folder named `<DATE_STAMP>.csv`** with files inside with long complex names. Spark does not allow you to control the file names. This is the core concept of parallel writing in spark - each worker works with a separate file, and the filename is a means to ensuring write isolation.

Comment: As some other comments mention, you can rename files afterwards if that's your requirement. Also note that `_SUCCESS` file is written once spark finishes writing - once this file is present, it's safe to copy/rename the data files.